# Where do I add "onclick" for my custom button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm following an example from W3Schools. After adding the CSS this creates a very nice looking button. Where do I add "onclick" I have tried several places but none work. I'm trying to call a function called myfuction() and it doesn't take any parameters.

```
    <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
```

The full example is found here.. [W3Schools "How to Create a Toggle Switch"](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

Comment: `$(".switch").click(function(){});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put onclick event in input type

```
<input type="checkbox" checked onclick="myfuction()">
```

JS

```
function myfuction(){
 alert("hi")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.

```js
$(function() {
$(document).on('click', '.switch', function(){
    myFunction();
}); 

});

function myFunction() 
{
  alert('Here');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>


<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind label to click event with a jquery event

Access a label via its class

```
$(".switch").click(function(){
    myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the `change` event instead of `click`. However, you will probably still need to check whether or not the checkbox is checked:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        console.log("checkbox changed");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.switch{position:relative;display:inline-block;width:60px;height:34px}.switch input{display:none}.slider{position:absolute;cursor:pointer;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:#ccc;-webkit-transition:.4s;transition:.4s}.slider:before{position:absolute;content:"";height:26px;width:26px;left:4px;bottom:4px;background-color:#fff;-webkit-transition:.4s;transition:.4s}input:checked+.slider{background-color:#2196F3}input:focus+.slider{box-shadow:0 0 1px #2196F3}input:checked+.slider:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(26px);-ms-transform:translateX(26px);transform:translateX(26px)}.slider.round{border-radius:34px}.slider.round:before{border-radius:50%}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Would you please check above snippet?